# Where are crash dumps in Windows 10 Mobile Creators update?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile, crash-dumps

In Win 10 Mobile was setting for developers where I could set the count of crash dumps must be saved on a device. After installing Creators Update that setting  disappeared and crash dumps are not saving anymore. Is it possibble to save crash dumps on a device with Creators Update ? It's necessary for me.
I know about app insights, but it's not variant - I need a full dump with native symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft changed this since Windows 10 Mobile Creators update v1703. After [activating Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development#additional-developer-mode-features) use your development PC and open the Device portal Url that is shown on the phone.

Now the updated device portal has an entry `Crash data` which you have to click

[image]

Now it takes around 30 seconds where the phone enumerates all sideloaded apps, lists them and offers you a checkbox to create dumps for each sideloaded app

[image]

So with the updated device portal you can now control the dump creation per sideloaded app instead of a global dump count. But I have no idea how many dumps are created, because I haven't got a crash.