# Windows 10 Mobile Error reporting not available

Tags: windows-10-mobile, error-reporting

According to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development), Windows 10 Mobile has an option for collecting error Reports amongst the developer Options (see screenshot).
Error Reports are created automatically if a sideloaded app crashes and can either be retrieved from the phone's file System via USB or from the Device Portal

[image: Error reporting Option Windows phone]

On my phones (I tested four different devices), this option is not available.
OS Versions tested:

- 10.0.15063.414
- 10.0.15063.540
- 10.0.15228.0 (Insider build, slow ring)
- 10.0.15245.0 (Insider build, fast ring)

Here is what the developer options look like for me. The error reporting option simply isn'nt there:

[image: No Error reporting option]

I didn't find any Information about this feature being moved or removed.
Does anyone know how to enable error reporting for current Windows 10 mobile builds?

Comment: [this was already asked some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44834115/1466046) but nobody can answer it. in the last Fast Ring Builds the option is still missing.

Comment: yes, it was removed in Creators update v1703 - Build 15063.

Comment: nope, no idea how to change this back. submit it to MS via feedback hub app

Comment: ok, MSFT changed this a bit. See [my answer to the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46261151/1466046)

Comment: have you tried what I wrote in the answer in the other topic? does this work?

Comment: no, this would be a duplicate. upvote the other answer so that I can vote to close the question as duplicate.